# Возможности Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

В сравнении с `Notepad++`:

1. Есть ли поддержка макросов в `VSC`? Есть ли поддержка макросов, записываемых автоматически, как последовательность действий, выполненных после включения записи?
2. Есть ли в `VSC` возможность выполнить поиск по регулярному выражению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Нет, Microsoft насколько помню отказалась от макросов еще в 2012м 
2 - Да! есть. https://professorweb.ru/my/programs/visual-studio/level2/2_1.php

Comment: Они просто так отказались или нашли им приемлемую замену?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)